# Duplicate computer name but one of them with SID

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have seen duplicate computer name in AD.

e.g. One PC was call 456 and the other called 456 cnf:850255521

Why they are two same PC name, I have ask everyone but know one knows why.

Can someone please explain why system will have same name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because two objects with the same name were created on different domain controllers before the change was replicated to the other.  Duplicates cannot exist so the first one got renamed.

(Possibly an admin made the computer account manually on one DC and then joined using the other DC?)

Pick the one that is in use and delete the other.

Comment: We only have one domain

Comment: domain controller

Comment: OK I do understand. That mean when I have two user account with same account but one with sid in logon is also having same problem